# Replace shell variables in a file with their actual values

Tags: shell, sh

Is it possible to insert variable defined in shell file into string that was read from another file? (In this sample it's just 1 variable to insert but I'll need many)

E.g. have file *example.txt*

```
Hello $WORLD
```

And script file

```
#!/bin/sh
WORLD=world!
FILE_STRING=$(cat example.txt)
echo $FILE_STRING
```

Running this script I have

```
Hello $WORLD
```

But I want to have

```
Hello world!
```

Comment: Can you use `envsubst`?

Comment: @Inian in current example WORLD isn't a environment variable and envsubst doesn't work in this case. Of course I can define variable like `export WORLD=world!` and envsubst will resolve my question, but idea is to do it with simple shell variables

Comment: It doesn't have to be exported, you can export variables locally also `WORLD=world! envsubst < example.txt`

Comment: `bash` isn't a good choice for a templating language. You are starting with the assumption that there's a good way to accomplish this. Choose a different templating language instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `envsubst` from GNU gettext-runtime to dynamically substitute variable values from files.

```sh
WORLD=world! envsubst < example.txt
```

or even more succinctly, refer variables by name that you want to substitute,

```sh
WORLD=world! envsubst '$WORLD' < example.txt
```

and store the result in a variable using command substitution `$(..)`

```sh
FILE_STRING="$(WORLD=world! envsubst '$WORLD' < example.txt)"
```

---

As a better practice, always use lower case variable names for referring user defined variables, so that they are *not* misinterpreted as environment variables.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the easiest option is to use "eval" before the echo.

For script file:

```
#!/bin/sh
WORLD=world!
FILE_STRING=$(cat example.txt)
eval echo $FILE_STRING
```

If you want to learn more about eval, you can take a look here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/eval.htm
https://linuxhint.com/bash_eval_command/

Comment: ... and if you want to learn more about the perils of eval, you can take a look  [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278427/why-and-when-should-eval-use-be-avoided-in-shell-scripts)